# Split n numbers into k lists with equal size, which any different combination of m lists contains all the n numbers

Tags: combinatorics, extremal-combinatorics

I'm triyng to find an answer for this qustion...

Lets say I have a range of {0, 1, ... , r} numbers, where I need to choose sub range of n size, which I want to divide into k equal size lists.
I can use the same value multiple time, and the order isnt important.

The condition is that after the partition, each m lists (from the total k) must contains all values, and there isn't any m-1 lists that holds this condition.

My question is how I can find the maximum n value that can performs this procedure?

Comment: I'm having some difficulty understanding exactly what you mean. Could you give an example?

Comment: Yes offcourse, for example:
I have a total of 8 numbers, I want to find the maximum number from {0, ..., 8} that I can split the range {0, .., n} into 4 lists, where any 2 lists from to 4 will contains all the numbers.
So in this example the number will be 3 and the partition will be [[0, 1, 2], [0, 1, 3], [0, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3]]

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).